# Jquery scrollTop z-index -1

Tags: jquery, z-index, opacity, parallax, scrolltop

I'm trying to use z-index as -1 when the scrolltop opacity hits invisible at 250px. It fires off when the document is loaded and has a z-index of -1 in the beginning... What am I doing wrong?

```
function ScrollParallax() {
  scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('#introtext').css({
    'opacity': 1-(scrollPos/250),
    'z-index': '-1' + 1-(scrollPos/250)
  });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($(window).width() > 1023) {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    ScrollParallax();
  });

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most practical way of fixing, but this is my best knowledge.

Happy Coding

```
function ScrollParallax() {
  scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('#introtext').css({
    'opacity': 1-(scrollPos/300)
  });

if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
  $('#introtext').css( "z-index", "-1" );
}

if ($(this).scrollTop() < 300) {
  $('#introtext').css( "z-index", "1" );
}

}
$(document).ready(function () {

if ($(window).width() > 1023) {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    ScrollParallax();
  });

}
});
```